# How is the normal vector to the parabola $r(t)=(t,t^2)$ calculated?

Tags: calculus, parametrization

I think the parametrisation of a parabola ought to be like so:

- $r(t)=(t,t^2)$

When I compute $r'(t)$ I get $r'(t)=(1,2t)$, and when I compute $r''(t)$ I get $r''(t)=(0,2)$. At each point $0i + 2j$ isn't orthogonal to the tangent everywhere. What is the correct normal vector calculation?

Comment: How can a fixed vector be the normal vector to a curve?

Comment: @Raffaele if the curve is a straight line, I suppose

Comment: to OP: You already know you're not right, so why do you want to check if you're right? $r''$ is a normal if you use arclength, and you did not. Another thing you can do is rotate $r'$ by 90º

Comment: That is my point! What is the mistake in calculating the normal vector that I've went and made haha!?

Comment: To check if you are right just compute the scalar product between $a=(t,t^2)$ and $b=(0,2)$, for $t\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Rem I might be wrong, but I feel like that calculation is implied to have been done by OP when OP said  "at each point $0i + 2j$ isn't orthogonal to the tangent." Also you need to use $a=(1,2t)$ not $(t,t^2)$.

Comment: @calvinkhor How can I use arc length then?

Comment: @CalvinKhor No you are right, I did not see they wanted $(0,2)$ to be orthogonal to the tangent. Also, when I answered the question was "How can I check if I am wrong?".

Comment: Well, it turns out using arclength is [not possible](http://%5Cleft(F%5Cleft(t%5Cright),F%5Cleft(t%5Cright)%5E%7B2%7D%5Cright)) in explicit elementary functions for the parabola. I suppose you could use the formula for the derivative of an inverse function to compute the normal anyway

Comment: Oh well it looks like I forgot to just divide $r(t)$ by $|r'(t)|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There is a fact](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/TangentNormalVectors.aspx) that if $r(t)$ is a vector such that $\| r(t) \|$ is constant, then $r'(t)$ is orthogonal to $r(t)$. So, to fix your calculations you can first normalize $r'(t)$ to have constant magnitude, and then calculate the second derivative.

**Edit**: the start of the first step is to calculate
$$\| r'(t) \| = \sqrt{1^2 + (2t)^2 } = \sqrt{1 + 4t^2}, $$
so our unit tangent vector is
$$T(t) = \left\langle \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + 4t^2}}, \frac{2t}{\sqrt{1 + 4t^2}} \right\rangle.$$

Comment: I actually need to know how to calculate the correct vector, so I have edited the post title!

Comment: That was the intent of my second sentence: first make $r'(t)$ have norm 1, and then take the derivative. Should I elaborate more?

Comment: Well if by make $r'(t)$ have norm 1 you mean divide $r'(t)$ by $|r'(t)|$ then I have almost got it....

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean--see the edit

Answer (score 1):

Rotating a vector $(a,b)$ by 90 degrees counterclockwise yields $(-b,a)$. The unit tangent vector to $r(t)=(t,t^2)$ is $$T(t)=\frac{r'(t)}{\|r'(t)\|}=\frac{(1,2t)}{\sqrt{1+4t^2}}.$$Rotate to obtain $$N(t)=\frac{(-2t,1)}{\sqrt{1+4t^2}}.$$

---

Bonus: plane curves can be studied with complex numbers. Then, rotation by 90 degrees counterclockwise amounts to multiplying by $\rm i$. So if $r(t)=t+t^2{\rm i}$, divide $r'(t)$ and ${\rm i}r'(t)$ by $|r'(t)|$ to reobtain $T(t)$ and $N(t)$.